# Codeigniter front controller location and proper .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, bonfire

How should my .htaccess code look like if I move my front controller? More specific, I had front controller in the following directory: `root/public/index.php` and my .htaccess looked like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Now when I move front controller to: `root/en/index.php` obviously my .htaccess becomes obosolete. Also I think I must change the path in my front controller? But lets fix the .htaccess first to work with the new structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be just a matter of rewriting:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I now get 404 Unable to find theme layout: index

Comment: Is your layout still under the public folder or under en?

Comment: themes and assets are still under public folder

Comment: Yeah that is why it cannot find them. I imagine your code (and codeigniter) assumes they are under the same directory. This will forward the request as if it hit the en directory to start with.

Comment: If I move them to the `root/en` they would be in the same folder as application directory, is this safe? I really just want to make my `root/en` the new root folder for my application

Comment: Sorry I work with Cakephp much more and it is a little different. Have you looked at this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/index.html ? I think this may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: accepted your answer as it helped me although not exactly as I wanted but my next question should really be another topic